# Is there a way to install, reinstall or update all the cordova plugins at once?

Tags: android, cordova

I have the plugins listed on the package.json and config.xml. All I want to do is run a command to install all of this plugins instead of run `$ cordova plugin add` several times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [cordova-check-plugins](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-check-plugins):

```
npm install -g cordova-check-plugins
```

Then from the root of your Cordova project where `config.xml` is located:

```
cordova-check-plugins --target=config --update=auto
```

This should install any plugins that are in your `config.xml` but not installed in your project. It will also update any plugins where the version specified in `config.xml` is newer than the installed version.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of `cordova-check-plugins`*

Comment: what's the difference between cordova-check-plugins and cordova prepare?

Comment: `cordova-check-plugins` will update existing plugins to versions specified in `config.xml`, as well as install those present in the `config.xml` but not installed locally. If all you want to do is install plugins which are not installed locally, you can just use `cordova prepare`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested from the SDK when the plugins enter in a corrupted state, it may be sufficent to just iterate through `add` and `remove` for all your installed `platforms`:

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova platform remove browser
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova platform add ios
ionic cordova platform add browser
```